# to add extra <Edittext> views on click of button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I used the following code but the editview layout appearing is in the bottom and i want it to get displayed on the top.
If anybody can please tell me what to do so that it get displayed on the top

```
private OnClickListener OnClick() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            EditText t = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            mLayout.addView(t);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: your edittext is not displayed??

Answer (score 2):

`mLayout.addView(t)` will add the new view at the end of the layout. Try to use `mLayout.addView(t, 0)` to add it as the first view in the layout.

Comment: This will not override another view. In a RelativeLayout the newly added View might lie over another view though.

Comment: but the cursor is stucked to the previous layout only ?? any suggestions for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the EditText in the layout by default, but with it's visibility set to `android:visibility="gone"`. This will cause the EditText to be present, but not visible. The rest of your layout will adjust for the View not being there.

Then in your onClick change the visibility on the EditText to `visible`. This will cause your UI to update with the now visible EditText.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mLayout.addView(t, 0);
```

where `0` indicates the position within the layout.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29).